# Parse JSON from within HTML webpage Using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to pull data from a website using Python. I have done stuff like this before, but the first time I came across pulling from a structure like this. It appears to be an html page with the json at the bottom. I am able to get the html using beautifulsoup, but I need to extract the json with the data in it.

There is a sample of my code below which does return the html with the json. I tried using request originally, but there was an issue with the script just running without anything happening so I used beautifulsoup with urllib. I assume it has something to do with the structure of the site.

here is a link to the site: https://www.bizbuysell.com/california-businesses-for-sale?q=aTI9ODEsNTcsMzA%3D

```py
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://www.bizbuysell.com/connecticut-businesses-for-sale/?q=bHQ9MzAsNDAsODA%3D"
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")
```

Comment: What information do you need to get from that page?

Comment: pretty much everything in the json elements. I am having an issue separating the json from the html. Once the json is separated from it, I can do whatever by just naming the data elements. I am trying to get data on each business posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example how to parse the Json data contained within this page:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bizbuysell.com/connecticut-businesses-for-sale/?q=bHQ9MzAsNDAsODA%3D"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one('[data-stype="searchResultsPage"]').contents[0]
data = json.loads(data)

# pretty print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "SearchResultsPage",
    "speakable": {
        "@type": "SpeakableSpecification",
        "xpath": [
            "/html/head/title",
            "/html/head/meta[@name='description']/@content"
        ]
    },
    "about": [
        {
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Moving  Company",
                "alternateName": null,
                "logo": "https://images.bizbuysell.com/shared/listings/179/1791243/ade90fd4-5537-4545-9011-58eb2f257a99-W496.jpg",
                "image": "https://images.bizbuysell.com/shared/listings/179/1791243/ade90fd4-5537-4545-9011-58eb2f257a99-W496.jpg",
                "description": "The company is made up of three department. A licensed Household Goods Relocation and Eviction, an Insurance Agency, and also a Thrift Store. The reason why the company is established this way is the three departments work very well together. Most times someone calls us for services and require special Insurance Coverages. We represent several Insurance Companies and Wholesalers which us a great advantage to obtain the required Insurance Coverage without delays.  Most time we relocate clients who are downsizing, children are grown, and moved out, and therefore do not have need for lots of furniture which we either purchase at minimal cost or given to us for free. It's a win win situation for the company. The items are sold very fast because the selling price is extremely low and the profit margin is very high.",
                "url": "/Business-Opportunity/moving-company/1791243",
                "productId": "1791243",
                "offers": {
                    "@type": "Offer",
                    "price": 450000,
                    "priceCurrency": "USD",
                    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "url": "/Business-Opportunity/moving-company/1791243",
                    "image": "https://images.bizbuysell.com/shared/listings/179/1791243/ade90fd4-5537-4545-9011-58eb2f257a99-W496.jpg",
                    "availableAtOrFrom": {
                        "@type": "Place",
                        "address": {
                            "@type": "PostalAddress",
                            "addressLocality": "Hartford County",
                            "addressRegion": " CT"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 0
        },

...
```

Comment: This is great! I assume I was having trouble with request before because I did not use a header. Could you explain the soup.select_one('[data-stype="searchResultsPage"]').contents[0]. understanding this seems like it would be helpful for me.

Comment: @j.doe `soup.select_one('[data-stype="searchResultsPage"]')` select one element with CSS selector `[data-stype="searchResultsPage"]` (tag that has `data-stype="searchResultsPage"` attribute). The access the first content of this tag using `.contents[0]`

Comment: Great! I was trying to grab it through the script type which wasn't working. now that you point it out, it seems clear as day.